# to_char(resolved_date-opened_date, 'hh24:mi')

Tags: postgresql, date-format

I am using the below to return the `hh:mm` difference between two date ranges. How would I update this code to minus the hours by 5?

CURRENT CODE = `to_char(resolved_datetime-opened_datetime, 'hh24:mi')`
CURRENT RESULTS = `06:35`

NEW RESULTS = `01:35`

resolved_datetime timestamp
opened_datetime timestamp

Comment: Both columns are timestamp

Comment: Please put all relevant information into the question itself! Use the edit link below your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can subtract the five hours from the resulting interval, before the formatting takes place:

```
to_char(resolved_datetime - opened_datetime - interval '5 hour', 'hh24:mi')
```

---

Note that `to_char(..., 'hh24:mi')` on an interval, might not give you what you want, if the difference is greater than 24 hours, e.g. an interval of `2 days 3 hours 5 minutes` formatted with that, will display as `03:05`, **not** as `51:05`